# Calculating Prices based on Rules (Ruby Rule Engine)

Tags: ruby, algorithm

there are a couple of rule engines like Treetop or Wongi::Engine, but none seem to fit my profile.

i want to build is a flexible system which can calculate prices. for e.g:

Base Price is 100€ for a sled

***Product Rule:***

- Rule_#0 a sled costs 100€

***Time Rule:***

- Rule_#1 you bought the sled after 23:00 H => you get an discount of 10 €

***Date Rule:***

- Rule_#2 you bought the sled on Christmas  => you gets an discount of 10% (10€)

***User Rule:***

- Rule_#3 Your Name is Santa  => you get an discount of 2€

Rules can also be combined (exclude/include):

=> Final Price is 100-10-10-2=78

Comment: please leave a comment why this question shows no effort/research or is not useful so i can improve my questions...

Comment: How does your question show effort or research? You have no code, and give no reason why the two mentioned gems don't fit your needs.

Comment: those 4 rules describe the logic, why is there a need to post ruby code ? i just thought to keep the question simple. i tried to figure out how to apply Wongi::Engine to my problem. but it seems too complex for that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no short-cut to solve your problem.

The price rules engine needs to know the underlying model, and be able to reference it. Generally the shortest, most efficient code to do these things already exists in e.g. ActiveResource or DataMapper. Any rules you could come up with will be most easily expressed directly in Ruby code that manipulates that model. Making that more abstract, via a DSL for pricing, is more work over the top of the rules you will be individually building. A pre-built DSL for product pricing does not exist outside of pre-packaged e-Commerce solutions (where the data model is known).

You are probably looking for an object-oriented design pattern, not a gem or library. And you have a lot of work ahead of you.