# Calculate price of service depending on lots of rules

Tags: ruby, rule-engine

I'd need to calculate the price for a service. The price is depending on a lot of rules which could be something like:

- day of week the service is consumed
- day of time the service is consumed (can overlap)
- type of customer (rebate for members)
- number of services consumed
- combination of services (cheaper if service a and service b is consumed at once)
- cost cap
- minimal price

Some of those rule might contradict (i.e. a rebate would result in a price below minimal price) and some can be combined. Also the rules based on time criterias are a bit tricky as the price needs to be calculated on the currently valid price: if price is:

- 5$ from 09:00 to 12:00
- 7$ from 12:01 to 08:59

and you consume the service from 11:00 to 13:00 then the total price is 12$ (5$ for first hour, 7$ for second hour)

Any hints on how one can implement this? I was thinking about using a rule engine but not sure how i would start this.

I looked into https://github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine and https://github.com/Ruleby/ruleby so far.

Also i found a similar question where one reply suggests to actually implement it in pure ruby: [Calculating Prices based on Rules (Ruby Rule Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869716/calculating-prices-based-on-rules-ruby-rule-engine)

The pricing model is not up for discussion unfortunately...i did not decide to have something that complex:-(

Comment: Although related to programming, I think your question is too broad.

Comment: What you implement this in could depend on how often the rules change, how quickly changes need to be applied, and who has to implement the changes. You would look for data-driven rules engines if control needs to be in hands of business managers - they will also need some kind of CMS. Whilst a Ruby implementation of something that is relatively static could be much easier as a first attempt. I agree this is too broad though - you will need to discuss elsewhere what approach/technology to use, and come back to SO if you are having problems implementing a specific rule.

Answer (score 1):

One  of the aspects you may take into consideration on top of the complexity of the rules is how often those rules can change and how fast you need to be able to react to those changes. I’ll ask myself the following questions:

- You want to edit the rules on the fly and hot deploy the changes to production?
- You want the business to be able to execute CRUD operations over the rules?

Answering those questions will help you also to decide what rule engine better fit with your final solution. There are quite few implementations of rule engines out there, some are lightweight and really easy to use but won’t allow the possibility of editing the rules on the fly, other are heavy and a bit hard to use but will provide editors and tools that will help you to implement a solution more robust and flexible for the customers and the business people.

There is a lot of good approach for rule engines you can use, **Drools** is one of then and it will allow you to define rules in a fair easy way. Drools also come with a tool named **Guvnor** that, with the proper configuration, will allow you to execute CRUD operations to rules and deploy it to production on the fly. Drools also allow you to create time activation rules that will make your life easy with those date/time base rules.

There are a lot of rule engine frameworks out there you can use but you’ll have a lot of work to do in your side to make those rules available no matter which framework you choose.

You can see some samples of rule engines in this page: http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/top-10-java-business-rule-engines/

If you don’t want to go with those heavy rule engines, we are creating a lightweight rule engine that is really easy to use. Is a Java base rule engine and the rules will be embedded in the code but I think have all the functionality you need to build your solutions using our Group/Rule hierarchy execution combined with the execution strategies, if you want to read more check  **EZ-Rules documentation @ Opnitech**: http://opnitech.com/content/products/ez-rules/ code is available **@ Github - EZ-Rules**